# Google data flow PCollection join

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline

We are streaming data from KAFKA and storing the same to google Bigtable.

Before writing to bigtable,a value needs to be caluculated based on the existing values from same table.
[image]

When a vehcile_id comes from kafka, I will have to check if the data is present already for the vehicle_id in bigtable. Based on the datetime present in bigtable for the vehicle_id, trip Id will be calculated.

```
    PCollection<String> ids = pipeline.apply(KafkaIO.<String,String>read().....)
    PCollection<com.google.bigtable.v2.Row> BTread =pipeline.apply("read", BigtableIO.read().....)
```

Any help on achieving the above requirement will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more how you calculate the trip_id? Why for Vehicle_id=1, trip_id=a1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few approaches you can take.

If you need to consider data already in BigTable you can create a second input source and feed that into a transform as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) or use [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey) transform to combine the two inputs.

If you need to consider data already being written by your pipeline you probably need to maintain some state to keep track of vehicle_ids already written. You can consider using the [Beam state API](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) for the latter (note though that the state will be unique to a Window and a key).

I'm not sure if any of these will be an exact fit for your application but wanted to give some pointers you can explore on.